# Would it be easier to apply for a UK visa if there is a host family to sponsor for you in going there?

Tags: visas, uk

Would it be easier to apply for a UK visa if there is a host family to sponsor for you in going there?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘easier’, and by ‘sponsor’? It is generally best if an applicant meets the visit visa eligibility requirements in their own right

Comment: It sounds like you're considering trying to find somebody who will sponsor your application. Don't do that: getting somebody you don't know to pretend that they know you is lying and that's a really bad idea. And if you admit that you don't know them, then they aren't believable sponsors.

Comment: +1: This is a nice clean question that doesn't lead to answers that go on tangents with the particulars of the asker's situation. It will be well suited as a duplicate target.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I strongly disagree. Visa applications are _all_ about the particulars of the case and this question looks very much like the asker is proposing to manufacture a sponsor.

Answer (score 21):

Having a "sponsor" for a visitor visa application helps in **only** these two cases:

- The plans for your trip that you present in the applications say you will stay in someone's home rather than in commercial accommodation such as a hotel. In that case the ECO needs to see proof that the people you're going to stay with are cool with that plan (and, in the case of the UK, also that they won't get into trouble with their landlord or council for boarding guests).
- Your economic circumstances make the ECO think: "This person cannot reasonably afford a vacation that's as expensive as what he has planned. Something's fishy -- he's probably intending to find work in the UK, which is not allowed." Then it can help *some* to explain that you're getting money for the trip from such-and-such people. The application must contain documents to prove that the sponsor *can* afford to pay for your trip, and a convincing explanation for why they'd *want* to pay for your trip. For this kind of sponsor it doesn't matter whether the sponsor is in the UK or outside it.

An applicant who **doesn't need either of those two** has much better chances than one who does need them (and provides them).

In particular, "sponsor" **does not mean anything even remotely like this:**

> Hmm, someone whom we already trust says this is a nice person that we should give a visa. They're probably right -- one of our own people wouldn't recommend a bad person, would they?

It also **doesn't mean anything like:**

> Whoops, since NN is a citizen they have a human right to be visited by their friends, so unless there are extra strong signs of wrongdoing we shouldn't refuse the application.

Comment: +1 It also doesn’t mean anything like ‘a remote family connection that suddenly makes an appearance’ or an ‘online friend’ whom you’ve never met in person. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/793361/Visit-guidance-v8.0ext.pdf#page28

Comment: This is a great answer and will be helpful to a long list of people on this site for a long time to come.

Comment: Regarding your last point, different rules apply to relatives who qualify as a dependent.

Comment: @o.m. I don't think they apply to *visitor* visas, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, good point.

Comment: What is a landlord council and also who is NN?

Comment: @AzorAhai it's landlord, or council.  The former is the owner of a building being rented out.  The latter is a local segment of the UK govt (loosely similar to a town or municipal govt elsewhere), that can among other things rent subsidized housing to poor residents.

Comment: @Azor NN was used as a placeholder for person's name.

Comment: @John I can see that, but why "NN"? Is it a typical British "John Doe"?

Comment: @AzorAhai https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomen_nescio

Comment: @moyli Huh, TIL. Never heard of that

Answer (score 8):

Maybe. Maybe not. The UK wants to be convinced that the visitor will leave again.

- If it is unclear how the visitor can afford the trip, there is the suspicion that he or she has taken on debt that will be repaid by working illegally in the UK. A sponsor helps to clarify how the visitor can afford the trip.
- If the visitor has few connections to his or her homeland and strong connections to the UK, there is the suspicion that the visitor wants to join family in the UK and overstay or "live there through successive visits." A sponsor hurts by underlining the ties to the UK.